# Use other sites element's id javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to get the title form an amazon product (Canon EF-S Teleobiettivo Compatto, 55-250 mm F/4-5.6 IS STM, Nero), how do i get that trought element's id? I wrote that but it shows nothing, if I don't put .innerHTML is shows "null"

```js
function writeText() {
  text1 = document.getElementById("http://www.amazon.it/dp/B00EP71ETU#productTitle");
  //document.write(text1.innerText)
  document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = (text1)
}
```

the "outputDiv" is just: `<div id="outputDiv"></div>` inside a body with a button that on click invoke  writeText()

Comment: In this case I'd suggest reading a book about javascript, because that's not even remotely how it works ?

Comment: Are you passing a url to `getElementById` in the expectation it will acquire the element from that page? It won't, that's not how it works; even if it did you cannot interact with the document of a page hosted on a different domain than your own.  To do this correctly you would use Amazons Web Service API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use `getElementId` to access the DOM of another page. For something like this, you'd need to use ajax to get the Amazon page, and then parse that result for the id you're looking for.

If you can use jQuery, generally you'd be able to use their `load` method to get a page from an external site:

```
$( "#outputDiv" ).load( "http://www.amazon.it/dp/B00EP71ETU #productTitle" );
```

In this case, however, Amazon doesn't allow [Cross-site HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), so if you went this route you'd probably have to run the ajax call through a proxy to access the external page, using something like this:

```
$.get( "proxy.php", { url: "http://www.amazon.it/dp/B00EP71ETU" }, function(data){
    var $html        = $(data),
        productTitle = $html.find('#productTitle').text();

       $('#outputDiv').text(productTitle);
} );
```